# Add new tool to galaxy

Tags: ngs, galaxy

I am trying to include a new tool to the galaxy main menu, following [these](https://galaxyproject.org/admin/tools/add-tool-tutorial/) instructions.
`tool_conf.xml` doesn't exists only `tool_conf.xml.main` and `tool_conf.xml.sample` and none of them seem to be working. I make changes and nothing happens when I run galaxy.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The .main and .sample file files usually come with default installations and may have been removed by whoever setup this Galaxy instance. You can look at the originals online and just base your own file on those: https://github.com/galaxyproject/galaxy/blob/dev/lib/galaxy/config/sample/tool_conf.xml.sample

Comment: Thanks @Devon, I removed the suffix `.sample` and it worked. I believe that galaxy folks could improve/update their manual.